# Python BeautifulSoup - Add Tags around found keyword

Tags: python, html, insert, tags, beautifulsoup

I am currently working on a project in which I want to allow regex search in/on a huge set of HTML files.

After first pinpointing the files of my interest I now want to highlight the found keyword!

Using BeautifulSoup I can determine the Node in which my keyword is found. One thing I do is changing the color of the whole parent.

However, I would also like to add my own <span>-Tags around just they keyword(s) I found.

Determining the position and such is no big deal using the find()-functions provided by BFSoup. But adding my tags around regular text seems to be impossible?

```
# match = keyword found by another regex
# node = the node I found using the soup.find(text=myRE)
node.parent.setString(node.replace(match, "<myspan>"+match+"</myspan>"))
```

This way I only add mere text and not a proper Tag, as the document is not freshly parsed, which I hope to avoid!

I hope my problem became a little clear :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a simple example showing one way to do it:

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup

html = '''
<html><body><p>This is a paragraph</p></body></html>
'''
```

(1) store the text and empty the tag

```
soup = Soup(html)
text = soup.p.string
soup.p.clear()
print soup
```

(2) get start and end positions of the words to be boldened (apologies for my English)

```
match = re.search(r'\ba\b', text)
start, end = match.start(), match.end()
```

(3) split the text and add the first part

```
soup.p.append(text[:start])
print soup
```

(4) create a  tag, add the relevant text to it and append it to the parent

```
b = soup.new_tag('b')
b.append(text[start:end])
soup.p.append(b)
print soup
```

(5) append the rest of the text

```
soup.p.append(text[end:])
print soup
```

here is the output from above:

```
<html><body><p></p></body></html>
<html><body><p>This is </p></body></html>
<html><body><p>This is <b>a</b></p></body></html>
<html><body><p>This is <b>a</b> paragraph</p></body></html>
```

Comment: It's not what I did in the end, but it is close to what I had in mind! So I accepted this answer, as it solves the problem! I am going to change my implementation. Didn't know I could append text and Tags to a node :) Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If you add the text...

```
my_tag = node.parent.setString(node.replace(match, "<myspan>"+match+"</myspan>"))
```

...and pass it through BeautifulSoup once more

```
new_soup = BeautifulSoup(my_tag)
```

it should be classified as a BS tag object and available for parsing.

You could apply these changes to the original mass of text and run it through as a whole, to avoid repetition.

EDIT:

From the [docs](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html):

```
# Here is a more complex example that replaces one tag with another: 

from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup, Tag
soup = BeautifulSoup("<b>Argh!<a>Foo</a></b><i>Blah!</i>")
tag = Tag(soup, "newTag", [("id", 1)])
tag.insert(0, "Hooray!")
soup.a.replaceWith(tag)
print soup
# <b>Argh!<newTag id="1">Hooray!</newTag></b><i>Blah!</i>
```

Comment: setString does not return anything. BeatifulSoup(node) doesn't change the main soup. Hence, I would need to parse the whole file again with my changes made, which I am looking to avoid!

Comment: This doesn't help either :( Here they are replacing the whole <a>-Tag with a custom one. However, I dont have a tag. I just have a few words withing a bunch of words which I want to surround with a new Tag. So one idea would be creating another Soup and replacing the whole node, if that's what you mean :) However, that wouldn't be a nice solution as the parent can be arbitrarily big. A better way would be to tell BFSoup to just reparse a certain node and incorporate it into the DOM, which I cannot find a way for.